# How to show a random variable is power law distributed and estimate its parameter?

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, power-law

According to [this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/idl/papers/ranking/ranking.html) the power-law distribution can be written as $$P(X=f) = \frac{1}{Z}f^{1+\frac{1}{b}}$$ where $f$ is the frequency of random variable $X$, $Z$ is the normalizing constant, and $b$ is the parameter of the power-law distribution. How can I estimate the $b$ parameter?

Comment: What has the question got to do with the title? Why do you use capital letters for constants? And $f$ for a random variable? If you are quoting a paper, and are not familiar with standard notation conventions, why change the notation from that used in the paper?

Comment: @wolfies $f$ is a constant, $X$ is a random variable, $Z$ is the normalization constant which is typically shown by capital $Z$. The title is related to the question: how to show something is power law distributed, given the power formula is such.

Comment: Well, no. Capitals are used for random variables (not constants). Standard notation might be $P(X=x)$ where the lower case $x$ denotes a particular realisation of the random variable. Your use of $f$ for same is frankly bizarre. And no - your title `How to show a random variable is power law distributed?` has absolutely nothing to do with your question: "How can I estimate the parameter $b$".

Comment: @wolfies - how do you show a random variable is power law distributed?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to show that your DATA is well approximated by a Zipf distribution?

Comment: @wolfies Zipf or Power law - and if it is [i.e. by looking at the plotted data], what is the parameter of that distribution...

Comment: The title and the question in the body text are asking quite different things. Which is your question?

Comment: updated the question title.

Comment: In what way is:  "$f$ is the frequency of random variable $X$"

Answer (score 6):

The answer is rather complicated. This paper, Clauset et al, "[Power law distributions in empirical data](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062.pdf)," walks through a number of methods and provides good commentary on why some approaches are better than others.

The paramaterization that you provide is not one that I typically encounter, though it should be clear how it relates to the estimator below. More usually, the power law probability distribution has form

$$p(x) \propto x^{-\alpha}$$

I would recommend focusing on this form, because is is used in the Clauset article, which is the most complete treatment of your question that I am aware of.

The MLE of the power law distribution for continuous data is
$$
\hat{\alpha}=1+n\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}\right]^{-1}
$$

The MLE in the discrete case is somewhat more involved, but an approximation to the exact MLE has a form very similar to that of the continuous case.

While plotting data that you suspect to be power law on log axes will probably resemble a straight line. Some authors just that as a justification for using a linear regression to estimate the scaling parameters. Clauset et al recommend against that procedure, as its estimates are not nearly as good as the MLE or other methods. There is a discussion of the disadvantages in the paper.

Considering whether the power law fit to the data is *plausible* is covered in section 4 of the paper. The authors suggest a Monte Carlo procedure to estimating the p-value.

Superficially, it might seem helpful to use something like a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of the data sample against the model attained by parameters directly estimated from the data. [**This is an incorrect application of the test**](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm), though, because the test assumes the model is fully specified, i.e. not estimated from the data. In the case where the data is used to estimate the parameters, there will be a natural and obvious dependence between the data and those parameters, so the test will be biased.

Comment: Maybe you could summarize the main results? ;)

Comment: I was thinking to use the expectation of X, and the data I have to fit the expectation "curve" to the data, from which I can extract the $b$. may be?

Comment: @user3639557 That seems rather *ad hoc.* Why would you do that instead of using an estimator which provably has desirable statistical properties?

Comment: @Tim I've expanded my answer.